# How to map ESCAPE key to CAPS LOCK in mac os x?

Tags: macos, keyboard, escaping, capslock

Many posts ask how to map the CAPS LOCK key to ESC. I know how to do that, but when I do, I lose the CAPS LOCK functionality all together because ESC still is mapped to escape. I want to SWAP the escape key to the capslock key (hitting caps lock key escapes and hitting escape key capslocks).

There is no remapping of the escape key through the
[settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC3JM.png)

Answer (score 0):

While it is not an exact answer - You can now preserve caps lock functionality by overloading the function key on a mac book.

Navigate to
Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys

Map the Caps Lock key to Escape and map the Function (fn) Key to Caps Lock.

Pressing fn will toggle caps lock, and by default holding down fn will still display the function keys on the touchbar. So you don't really loose fn functionality, you just have to check if you are in capslock after you use it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  While it does provide a solution, the solution doesn't involve mapping the ESC key to CAPS LOCK.